# "Node" does not name a type

Tags: c++

I have three classes Node, Pattern and Motor, all of them in the same directory
in Pattern class I defined a function of type Node, but the program doesn't compile, could you please help?

Here's all the files:

Node.h:

```
#ifndef Node_h
#define Node_h

#include "Arduino.h"
#include "Motor.h"
#include "Pattern.h"
#include "QueueArray.h"

class Node
{
public:
Node();
~Node();
int amplitude;
int duration;
void setPatternNode(int amplitude,int duration);

};

#endif
```

Node .cpp:

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "Node.h"
#include "Motor.h"
#include "Pattern.h"
#include "QueueArray.h"


Node::Node(){}
Node::~Node(){}

void Node::setPatternNode(int amplitude,int duration){
Node.amplitude=amplitude;
Node.duration=duration;
}
```

Pattern.h

```
#ifndef Pattern_h
#define Pattern_h

#include "Arduino.h"
#include "Node.h"
#include "QueueArray.h"
#include "Motor.h"

class Pattern
{
public:
    Pattern();
    ~Pattern();
    Node setPattern(int amplitude[3],int duration[3]); 

};

#endif
```

Pattern.cpp:

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "Pattern.h"
#include "Node.h"
#include "QueueArray.h"
#include "Motor.h"

Pattern::Pattern(){}
Pattern::~Pattern(){}


Node Pattern::setPattern(int amplitude[3],int duration[3]){
QueueArray <Node> pattern;
for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
Node node;
node.setPatternNode(amplitude[i],duration[i]);
pattern.enqueue(pattern);
}
return pattern;
}
```

Motor.h:

```
#ifndef Motor_h
#define Motor_h

#include "Arduino.h"
#include "QueueArray.h"
#include "Node.h"
#include "Pattern.h"

class Motor
{
public:
Motor(int pin);
~Motor();
void runMotor();
int _pin;
bool isMotorActive;
void motorSetPattern(Node p);
Node currentPattern;

};

#endif
```

Motor.cpp:

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "Motor.h"
#include "QueueArray.h"
#include "Node.h"
#include "Pattern.h"

Motor::Motor(int pin)
{
pinMode(pin, OUTPUT);
_pin = pin;
}

Motor::~Motor(){}

void Motor::runMotor(){

 if(isMotorActive){
    pattern.dequeue(); 
    if(patternStartTime < currentPattern.duration){
        analogWrite(_pin,currentPattern.amplitute);
    } else{
        pattern.dequeue();
        if(pattern.isEmpty()){
            isMotorActive = false;
            currentPattern = null;
        }
    }
  }
}

void Motor::motorSetPattern(Node p){
currentPattern = p;
isMotorActive = true;
unsigned long patternStartTime = millis();  
}
```

sketch:

```
#include <Motor.h>
#include <Node.h>
#include <Pattern.h>
#include <QueueArray.h>

Motor vibmotor(13);
Node node;
Pattern pattern;

int amplitude[3] = {5,2,0};
int duration[3] = {1000,2000,1000};

void setup()
{  
}  

void loop()
{  
pattern.setPattern(amplitude,duration);
vibmotor.runMotor();
}
```

Error:

```
In file included from C:\Users\Yacine\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Motor/Node.h:6,
             from C:\Users\Yacine\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Motor/Motor.h:6,
             from mc_ino.ino:1:
C:\Users\Yacine\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Motor/Pattern.h:14: error: 'Node' does not      name a type
mc_ino.ino: In function 'void loop()':
mc_ino:21: error: 'class Pattern' has no member named 'setPattern'
```

Comment: **TMC;DR;DC** Probably a cyclic include. Don't do that.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense in C++: `Node.amplitude=amplitude;`.

Answer (score 4):

You have at least one circular dependency in your #includes.

Your *Node.h* file includes *Motor.h*, which refers to `Node`. When Node.h includes Motor.h, Motor.h refers to Node before it's defined.

If you're coming from Java, you may be thinking of a `#include` like a Java import. However, a #include doesn't just import a type name. During preprocessing, the #include is replaced with the contents of the #include'd file. Circular #include's require more attention.

One thing you can do is a **forward declaration** of the class, in motor.h:

```
class Node;
```

However, this only works if you're using pointers or references to the class, so you'd need to change the signature of this method:

```
 #include "Node.h"

class Node;

class Motor
{
public: 
    ...
    void motorSetPattern( const Node & p);
    ...
};
```